# Trying to do C2DM service,but not getting registrationID from server

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am trying to do C2DM service in my Android app. I referring this [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) for help.

But not able to get `registrationID` from C2DM server. I think it may be the issue of `appID` that I am sending to C2DM server.

Actually I am giving like this for `appId`:

```
intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
```

Is it ok or anything else should be added. Please help me in this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I work with the following link provided by google.And it works fine.
Make sure you have Market Sync on your Android device.

[C2DM Google documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to sort out your problem, if you paste your manifest code in your question. For more precaution please check your manifest by following two steps.

1) = Have you added following permissions in your manifest ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  
<permission android:name="com.yourpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.yourpackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

2) = Have you added following lines within your application tag ?

```
<service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">       
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.yourpackage" />
        </intent-filter>        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.yourpackage" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Note:- **Please replace "com.yourpackage" according to your project.**